# How do I resolve a plugin conflict in Eclipse?

Tags: ide, eclipse, plugins

I'd like to upgrade my Helios installation of Eclipse to Indigo.  When I do, I get the following message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
  Software currently installed: Oracle GlassFish Server Tools 1.6.1.201009290929 (oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.glassfish.feature.group 1.6.1.201009290929)
```

So my first thought was to simply uninstall GlassFish.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how and where to go to do this.  I went to Help->About Eclipse...->Installation Details.  The only place that it looks like I can uninstall stuff is in the "Installed Software" tab.  I do not see the Oracle Glassfish package anywhere.  If I go to "Feature" or "Plug-ins", I can find it just fine, but there is no option to uninstall.

So my next thought was to upgrade Glassfish.  So I put the indigo repo in there, but I still get the same message when trying to update.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JasonThompson hopefully `oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.glassfish.feature.group` would show up in the Installed Software tab, as it's not part of the epp.package products.  Can you expand anything in Installed Software and see it there?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism within Eclipse to permanently and physically uninstall a feature and its plug-ins. The process to physically and permanently remove an undesirable feature and its plug-ins is a manual process that should be done when Eclipse is not running. In order to do, you will have to manually remove the files there associated with the feature from the eclipse/features directory and its plug-ins from the eclipse/plugins directory.

```
D:\Softwares\eclipse-standard-kepler-R-win32\eclipse\plugins\eclipse\
-plugins
-features
```